# The best practice for multi-thread test to catch race condition

Tags: spring, multithreading, testing

I have small rest controller for parking service.

```
@PostMapping("/entry")
public ResponseEntity<ResponseObject> carEntry(@Valid @RequestBody CarAtParkingGateRequest carAtParkingGateRequest) {
    return parkingService.carEntry(carAtParkingGateRequest);
}
```

In CarAtParkingGateRequest I am sending pair of ID's - car and parking.

Method parkingService.carEntry looks almost like:

```
public ResponseEntity<ResponseObject> carEntry(CarAtParkingGateRequest carAtParkingGateRequest) {
    ParkingEntity parking = findParking(carAtParkingGateRequest.getParkingID());
    CarEntity car = carService.findCar(carAtParkingGateRequest.getCarID());
    
    if (car.getPowerType().equals(PowerType.ELECTRIC) &&
            carRepository.getNumberOfElectricCarsOnParking(parking.getIdParking()) == parking.getNumberOfChargers()) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new ResponseObject("Every charger is taken"), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    } else if (!car.getPowerType().equals(PowerType.ELECTRIC) &&
            carRepository.getNumberOfNotElectricCarsOnParking(parking.getIdParking()) == parking.getNumberOfParkingSlots()) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new ResponseObject("Every slot is taken"), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    } else {
        parking.addCar(car);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(
                new ResponseObject("Gate up"), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Now I want to work on race condition and prepare test for it. I think, I have to use 2 threads with different requests which will be starting at the same time, but I do not know exacly how should it looks - how to send 2 requests in the same time for unit case

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Provoking a race condition in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446052/provoking-a-race-condition-in-java)

Comment: A bit, but still I do not know how to send that requests in different threads